# Adding leading Zeros if number is not 8 chars long

Tags: python

How can I make the Code add leading zeros to my strings (containing only 1s and 0s) IF it is shorter than 8 chars?

Comment: `str(mystring).zfill(8)`

Comment: why would we need a `str()` if it's already a string as OP says?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple list comprehension to do this as in the below piece of code:

```
# example list to work with
In [71]: list_of_str = ["101010", "10101010", "11110", "0000"]

In [72]: res = ["0"*(8-len(s)) + s if len(s) < 8 else s for s in list_of_str]

In [73]: res
Out[73]: ['00101010', '10101010', '00011110', '00000000']
```

Comment: I don't know why there was a downvote. This is a different approach to solve the same problem but not an incorrect one.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted, but perhaps you can add this answer to the dupe target instead of this duplicate question. It looks like an interesting solution and people might appreciate it there.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru thanks for the constructive feedback :) That's a good suggestion!